# How do I run an access query to pull only records with the current month from a date that is formatted as a short text?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have some tables that I cannot modify and a field "STAT_DATE" that is formatted as a short text like "yyyymmdd". I tried the Month(now()) functions and this did not work because the field is not in date format. I have also tried using the mid and monthname functions to try and match the current months name with the name of the digits that are meant to be the month in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Like` to compare your date text to the current date formatted as `'yyyymm\*'`

Here is an Immediate window session to demonstrate the technique:

```vb
' give STAT_DATE today's date ...
STAT_DATE = "20220913"
' display today's date as the yyyymm* pattern ...
? Format(Date(), "yyyymm\*")
202209*
? STAT_DATE Like Format(Date(), "yyyymm\*")
True
```

Then use that approach in a query:

```sql
SELECT y.*
FROM [Your Table] AS y
WHERE y.STAT_DATE Like Format(Date(), 'yyyymm\*');
```

If you're using ADO/OleDb to run your query, use `%` instead of `*` as the wildcard:

```sql
WHERE y.STAT_DATE Like Format(Date(), 'yyyymm\%');
```